# Setting a name for data

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB software to generate a set of data and save these data as a '.mat' file. There are some parameters on this file and I want to set a name for these '.mat' files according to the value of parameters. for example, if a=10,b=20, the name of '.mat' file would be 'data-10-20'. if a=20,b=30,the name of '.mat' file would be 'data-20-30' and so on.

Is there anybody who can help me?
Thanks

Comment: It is suggested and helpful to show what you have attempted.

Comment: `filename = ['data-' num2str(a) '-' num2str(b)]; save (filename)`

Comment: Thank Luis Mendo. It would make my work easier. Regards

Comment: or `filename = sprintf("data-%d-%d", param1, param2)`

Comment: Dear Jorj Tyron. Thanks a lot for your help